# Number of all sample divisions in permutation test

Tags: t-test, combinatorics, permutation-test, exact-test

I have a question with regard to the number of permutations in a 
permutation test. Assume I want to do a two group independent *t*-test. 
In the permutation variant of the *t*-test, I would repeatedly generate 
permutations of the group labels [e.g., (1, 2, 1, 2, ..., 1) ] and 
compute a *t* statistic for each iteration.

Assume that I want to do an exhaustive permutation test where I generate 
all possible divisions of the sample into two groups. According to Ernst 
(2004), "[c]omputation of the permutation distribution of a test 
statistic involves careful enumeration of all $\binom{N}{n}$ divisions 
of the observations." Here, $N$ is the total sample size and $n$ is the 
size of one of the groups. According to Ernst (2004) -- and all other 
references I found on this topic -- creating all "divisions of the 
observations" is accomplished by generating all permutations of the 
group labels.

However, generating all permutations of the group labels will result in 
duplicate "divisions of the observations" if the two groups are of equal 
size. For example, the permutations $(1, 1, 2, 2)$ and $(2, 2, 1, 1)$ 
clearly correspond to the same division, but they represent different 
permutations of the group labels. Therefore, the number of unique 
division of the observations not given by the binomial coefficient, but 
you have to divide it by 2 (for $K$ equal-sized groups, you have to divide the number of permutations of the group labels by $K!$). Note that no 
duplicates occur if the groups are of different size.

This results in several questions on my part: Has this matter been 
treated in any reference (I did not find any)? Has this issue been 
overlooked completely so far? Or is there a sensible reason to generate 
duplicate divisions in the case of equal group sizes? (note that you do 
not do that when you have unequal group sizes, so in my opinion this 
would be weird)

---

Ernst, M. D. (2004). Permutation methods: a basis for exact inference. 
*Statistical Science, 19*, 676-685.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no reason to generate duplicate divisions, except that they don't do a lot of harm and it is computationally expensive to avoid them. In practice, permutations are almost always drawn at random with replacement, see:

Phipson, B, and Smyth, GK (2010). Permutation p-values should never be zero: calculating exact p-values when permutations are randomly drawn. *Statistical Applications in Genetics and Molecular Biology* Volume 9, Issue 1, Article 39. https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05766

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Indeed I have read your paper and I was wondering if my point may have any implications with regard to a point you raise, i.e., sampling permutations *without* replacement. When sampling without replacement, I thought it might make sense to sample unique sample divisions rather than permutations? I agree that in practice distinguishing between partitions and permutations rarely matters.

Comment: Yes, assuming you are computing a two-sided test and the two groups are of equal sizes, it is theoretically optimal to sample unique sample divisions (excluding the original division). This is optimal in the sense that it produces maximum statistical power for the test for any given number of divisions. The ideal is to use all possible unique divisions exactly once.

Comment: your responses are very much appreciated!